# Can't find the request body on my POST request

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am using Node and Express to handle my back-end requests. I make a call from the front end:

```
          const newData = {id: sub, first_name: given_name, last_name: family_name, email: email}
          const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(newData)
        }
          fetch(`/add`, requestOptions)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => console.log(data))
          .catch(console.log('error2'));
```

which get picked up by my "/add" end-point.  For now I just want to `console.log` the request body so my end point is:

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

  console.log(req.body, 'hit')
})
```

However the server console log comes out as `{} 'hit'`.  When I use the network tab I can see that the request has a payload containing `id, first_name, last_name, and email`.

Could anyone tell me what I am missing to get my data into my server.

Also my server is set up with `body-parser` like this:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false,
    })
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are sending an `application/json` content type, you should use `bodyParser.json()` instead of `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })`.

Ex:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```